# Python: How to reverse integers using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am given a problem where I have to reverse given digits using recursion only, but the problem is when I try to print out the integer reversed, for example if the integer was 1234, it would print the reversed numbers partially once at a time, e.g: 21, 321, 4321. How can I fix this so that it can print 4321 in one go?

```
def reverse_digits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    else:
        reverse = str(n % 10) + str(reverse_digits(n // 10))
        print(reverse)
        return reverse
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to handle negative numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't have the function print anything at all, only returns the value, and you can print it when you call it:

```
def reverse_digits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    else:
        reverse = str(n % 10) + str(reverse_digits(n // 10))
        return reverse

print(reverse_digits(1234))
```

Output:

```
4321
```

If you still want the function to print, you can print each digit separately in the same line (using `end=''` in the print function):

```
def reverse_digits(n):
    if n < 10:
        print(n)  #  print the very last digit and add a newline
        return n
    else:
        print(n % 10, end='')  #  print the last digit so far and stay on the same line
        reverse = str(n % 10) + str(reverse_digits(n // 10))
        return reverse

reverse_digits(1234)
```

Output:

```
4321
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the print from within the function:

```py
def reverse_digits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    else:
        reverse = str(n % 10) + str(reverse_digits(n // 10))
        return reverse
print(reverse_digits(1234))
```